# Where are Outlook Tasks in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, calendars

In Windows Phone 8.1, the Outlook Tasks are located in the `Calendar app` > extend the application bar > `Tasks`

[image: Accessing Outlook tasks in Windows Phone 8.1]

But I can't find them in Windows Phone 10 Preview anymore. Where did they go ? Are they still accessible ?

Comment: Also gone from Windows 10 desktop calendar version. MS seems to be silently getting rid of tasks feature. Probably want you to move to Cortana reminders.

Comment: Surprisingly, I can view/update Hotmail/outlook calendar tasks on my iPhone or iPad but not on my Surface or Windows 10 desktop/laptop unless I log into my Microsoft account through a browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outlook on Windows 10 mobile is a lot similar to the new Outlook app on other platforms.
As you can see in the suggestion section on the Outlook for Android, this feature does'nt exists on Android. It is probably the same thing on Windows 10 mobile for the moment.

[image: Feature request for Outlook on Android]

Alternatively you could use Wunderlist (https://www.wunderlist.com/) which is cross-platform, and that Microsoft bought in 2015. (http://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2015/06/02/welcome-6wunderkinder-microsoft-acquires-wunderlist/)

Update: The lack of task support in outlook for the moment is officially acknowledged here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-specifications?OCID=win10_null_vanity_win10specs

Comment: Thanks (and also to the others) for you reply. In fact I already switched to Wunderlist before seeing your answer, so I can confirm that it's a good alternative :-)

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to find it either.  I did find a relatively cheap alternative.  It is an app called 2day.  It links with outlook.com and office365 (not sure the difference).  I chose outlook.com and so far so good.  It has a 30 day free trial.  The paid version is like $3 or $4 dollars.